# Socket disconnection after few minutes in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, sockets, tcplistener

Using .NET Core, I wrote a program that communicates with the device through the socket and the device sends its requests. Everything works fine, but after a few minutes (from half an hour to two hours), the connection is disconnected. And it doesn't send any log.

I don't know what's wrong? I want this connection to be permanent. Do I need to make a special adjustment? Or should I make a change?

```
  public async Task StartListening()
    {
        _logService.CreateLogCmd("StartListening get" + "ip&&port:" + ServerIP + " " + Port, "StartListening");

        this.tcp = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), Port);
        this.tcp.Start();
        _logService.CreateLogCmd("tcpStart" + "ip&&port:" + ServerIP + " " + Port, "StartListening");

        Socket mySocket = null;
        while (true)
        {
            mySocket = await tcp.AcceptSocketAsync();
            _logService.CreateLogCmd("AcceptSocket" + "ip&&port:" + ServerIP + " " + Port, "StartListening");
            mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize = MAXBUFFERSIZE;
            mySocket.SendBufferSize = MAXBUFFERSIZE;
            if (mySocket.Available <= 0)
                continue;
            byte[] bReceive = new byte[MAXBUFFERSIZE];
            mySocket.Receive(bReceive);
            Analysis(bReceive, mySocket);
        }
    }
```

This socket connection between the server and the device should remain stable forever and I don't know where the problem is

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sorry I edited my post tnx

Comment: TCP connections do automatically close. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712425/do-tcp-sockets-automatically-close-after-some-time-if-no-data-is-sent)